# Use fastlane to increment marketing version under build settings by scheme

Tags: xcode, fastlane

I am using fastlane and the [versioning plugin](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning) to try and set the `version number/marketing version` for different schemes according to the `marketing version` under `build settings` for each scheme.

`get_version_number_from_plist` works as expected and retrieves the `marketing version` for each scheme. My expected outcome is that `increment_version_number_in_plist` increment the `marketing version` in the `build settings` and use that value when building the app however its throwing this error

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    28: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
    27: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
    26: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
    24: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
    23: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:352:in `run'
    22: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    21: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
    20: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
    19: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    18: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    17: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    15: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    14: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    13: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    12: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    11: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    10: from Fastfile:28:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
     9: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
     8: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
     7: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
     6: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
     5: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
     4: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
     3: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
     2: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-plugin-versioning-0.4.4/lib/fastlane/plugin/versioning/actions/increment_version_number_in_plist.rb:53:in `run'
     1: from /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-plugin-versioning-0.4.4/lib/fastlane/plugin/versioning/actions/increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj.rb:44:in `run'
     /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.181.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-plugin-versioning-0.4.4/lib/fastlane/plugin/versioning/actions/increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj.rb:95:in `set_version_number_using_scheme':
```

Targets

```
MyApp
```

Relevant Schemes

```
MyApp
Stg_MyApp
```

Relevant Build configurations

```
Release
StgRelease
```

`get_version_number_from_plist` works fine and returns 3.3.0

```
get_version_number_from_plist(scheme: "MyApp", build_configuration_name: "Release", plist_build_setting_support: true); // returns 3.3.0
```

`increment_version_number_in_plist` throws an error and its not clear to me from the error log whats causing the error

```
increment_version_number_in_plist(scheme: "MyApp", build_configuration_name: "Release", plist_build_setting_support: true,  version_number:'3.4.0') // Error
```

Build Settings Marketing Version

[image: build settings marketing version]

info.plist

[image: info.plist]

Edit

I believe I have narrowed the error down to this line in the function `set_version_number_using_scheme_working` in [increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning/blob/3f7fc4afc49db29fc4b3ab889eaeaa80a94985c6/lib/fastlane/plugin/versioning/actions/increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj.rb#L90) but I'm not sure whats causing the error

```
project.build_settings["MARKETING_VERSION"] = next_version_number
```

I was able to get it working as intended by modifying the code for [set_all_xcodeproj_version_numbers](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning/blob/3f7fc4afc49db29fc4b3ab889eaeaa80a94985c6/lib/fastlane/plugin/versioning/actions/increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj.rb#L53) and looping through each config and comparing it with the `build_configuration_name param` I pass in

```
def self.set_version_number_using_scheme_working(params, next_version_number)
      project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(params[:xcodeproj])
      configs = project.objects.select { |obj| select_build_configuration_predicate(nil, obj) }
      configs.each do |config|
        if config.to_s === params[:build_configuration_name]
            config.build_settings["MARKETING_VERSION"] = next_version_number
        end
      end
      project.save
  end
```